# Unload Projects in Solution Folder not visible for a solution folder containing only .NET Standard 2.0 or .NET Core 2.2 projects in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

If I only have `.NET Standard 2.0` or `.NET Core 2.2` projects in a solution folder I can't use the function `Unload Projects in Solution Folder`.

[image]

If a `.NET Framework 4.6.1` project is added to the solution folder then the function `Unload Projects in Solution Folder` works and I can also use `Reload Projects in Solution Folder` without a problem. The function unloads/reloads all projects in the folder including `.NET Standard 2.0` and `.NET Core 2.2`.

[image]

Is this a bug or am I missing something here?

Comment: Just another quirk caused by the SDK-style .csproj file format.  Their integration into VS has never been stellar.

Comment: I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45820897/1997232) which makes me think core/standard is new and *improved*, so you don't need to unload them anymore.